# Divide ul elements into three divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am fetching ul elements dynamically and there are around 18 li's inside ul. All are coming in a single line. How could I divide into 3 divs through jquery

```html
<ul>
<li>Sample1</li>
<li>Sample2</li>
<li>Sample3</li>
<li>Sample4</li>
<li>Sample5</li>
<li>Sample6</li>
<li>Sample7</li>
<li>Sample8</li>
<li>Sample9</li>
<li>Sample10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can give example what you really want ?

Comment: you mean to say 3 different list blocks or 3 `div's` in which each has `ul`?

Comment: As of now it is something like this 
<ul>
<li>sample1</li>
<li>sample2></li>
I am expecting something like this:
<ul>
<div class="col-md-6">
<li>sample1</li>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<li>sample2</li>
</div>
</ul>

Comment: Hello @SagarReddy ! Please check my answer below. Hope it will help..

Comment: @SanchitGupta your code puts all li elements into a single line actually i want li elements to be divided and show few elements in one line and few elements in another line i.e side by side.

Comment: try my answer it should work as you expected grid system @SagarReddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment your need `<ul> <div class="col-md-6"> <li>sample1</li> </div> <div class="col-md-6"> <li>sample2</li> </div> </ul>`  You can use jQuery `wrap` function:-

```js
$(function(){
 
  $('#list >li').wrap("<div class=\"col-md-6\">");
 
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
   <ul id="list">
<li>Sample1</li>
<li>Sample2</li>
<li>Sample3</li>
<li>Sample4</li>
<li>Sample5</li>
<li>Sample6</li>
<li>Sample7</li>
<li>Sample8</li>
<li>Sample9</li>
<li>Sample10</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
        <ul id="list">
    <div class="col-md-6"><li>Sample1</li></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><li>Sample2</li></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><li>Sample3</li></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><li>Sample4</li></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><li>Sample5</li></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><li>Sample6</li></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><li>Sample7</li></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><li>Sample8</li></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><li>Sample9</li></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><li>Sample10</li></div>
    </ul>
```

Comment: but how can i select few li's and put into col-md-6 and remaining li's in another col-md-6?

Comment: if you  have 6 li means 3 in left side 3 in right side is it you want ? @SagarReddy

Comment: yeah exactly@jyothi

Comment: Your code helped me to get what i was expecting. highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
  var $bigList = $('#bigList'), group;
  while((group = $bigList.find('li:lt(3)').remove()).length){
    $('<ul/>').append(group).appendTo('body');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<ul id="bigList">
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
<li>w2way.com</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<ul id="bigList">
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
<li>w2way</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

script

```
  $(function(){
  var $bigList = $('#bigList'), group;
  while((group = $bigList.find('li:lt(3)').remove()).length){
    $('<ul/>').append(group).appendTo('body');
  }
});
```

Comment: please check it.

Comment: Your code is really appreciated but I think you got me wrong. Actually I was expecting li's to be divided into side by side. something like grid system i.e in col-md-6 around 6 li's and in another col-md-6 around 6 li's.

Comment: var $bigList = $('#bigList'), group; can u explain " ,group" in here.

Comment: @JaydeepGondaliya ! really nice. I have learnt new thing ie `group`. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with following Code :

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Sample1</li>
    <li>Sample2</li>
    <li>Sample3</li>
    <li>Sample4</li>
    <li>Sample5</li>
    <li>Sample6</li>
    <li>Sample7</li>
    <li>Sample8</li>
    <li>Sample9</li>
    <li>Sample10</li>
</ul>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    var items = $("ul>li");
    var wrapCount = 3;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i+= wrapCount) {
        var slice = items.slice(i,i + wrapCount);      
        slice.wrapAll("<div class='liwrapper'></div>");
    }
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/sanchit_/hfh5kcwo/)

Answer (score 0):

hope this works:

```
var allLi = $('#list li');
for (var i = 0; i < allLi.length; i += 3) {
    $("#list li").slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll("<div class=\"col-md-6\">");
}
```

Comment: @SagarReddy - i am using #list li ... you might want to change it according to your ul id . that might be the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://rawgit.com/fzondlo/jquery-columns/master/jquery-columns-plugin.js'></script>
<style>
ul.cols2 {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
}


</style>

<ul class='cols2'>
   <li>Sample1</li>
<li>Sample2</li>
<li>Sample3</li>
<li>Sample4</li>
<li>Sample5</li>
<li>Sample6</li>
<li>Sample7</li>
<li>Sample8</li>
<li>Sample9</li>
<li>Sample10</li>
</ul>

<div style='clear:both'></div>
```

```js
$('.cols2').cols(3);
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/fzondlo/jquery-columns/master/jquery-columns-plugin.js"></script>

<style>
ul.cols2 {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
}


</style>

<ul class='cols2'>
   <li>Sample1</li>
<li>Sample2</li>
<li>Sample3</li>
<li>Sample4</li>
<li>Sample5</li>
<li>Sample6</li>
<li>Sample7</li>
<li>Sample8</li>
<li>Sample9</li>
<li>Sample10</li>
</ul>

<div style='clear:both'></div>
```